# How to draw over other apps in React-native

Tags: react-native

I was trying to create Facebook messenger-like chat heads in my react-native app. I used pan responder to create the dragging effect and collapsing to side effect but I am not able to figure out how to make the chat heads visible over other apps or the home screen of the phone. My app has the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission included. Here is my code for the chat heads so far. Any lead would be appreciated.

```
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
const widthFactor = width / 375
const heightFactor = (Dimensions.get('window').height - 75) / 667

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      showDraggable: true,
      dropZoneValues: null,
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
    }

    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        {
          dx: this.state.pan.x,
          dy: this.state.pan.y,
        },
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
        if (this.isDropZone(gesture)) {
          this.setState({
            showDraggable: false,
          })
        } else {
          const k =
            gesture.dx > 0
              ? Window.width / 2 - CIRCLE_RADIUS
              : 0 - (Window.width / 2 - CIRCLE_RADIUS)
          if (gesture.moveY > Window.height - 2 * CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
            Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
              toValue: { x: k, y: Window.height - 2 * CIRCLE_RADIUS },
            }).start()
          } else {
            const y = gesture.dy
            Animated.spring(this.state.pan, { toValue: { x: k, y } }).start()
          }
        }
      },
    })
  }

  isDropZone(gesture) {
    const dz = this.state.dropZoneValues
    return gesture.moveY > dz.y && gesture.moveY < dz.y + dz.height
  }

  renderDraggable() {
    if (this.state.showDraggable) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
          <Animated.View
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), styles.circle]}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>Drag me!</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  setDropZoneValues(event) {
    this.setState({
      dropZoneValues: event.nativeEvent.layout,
    })
  }

  render() {
    that = this
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View
          onLayout={this.setDropZoneValues.bind(this)}
          style={styles.dropZone}
        >
          <Text style={styles.text}>Drop me here!</Text>
        </View>
        {this.renderDraggable()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw over other apps in React-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542175/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-react-native)

Comment: It does, sorry for the late reply. Thanks