# Show a button on screen when the app is in background (React Native)

Tags: react-native, notifications

I'm trying to figure out how the apps like ***facebook messenger*** shows a circle of user image on screen when a new message comes, and ***Uber driver*** app shows the uber icon on screen when the user minimizes it. Is there anyway that I can show a customized component on phone screen even when the app is not open?

Answer (score 1):

This Stackoverflow thread explains how to replicate in react native by changing the java code as its not supported by react native yet.

> this feature is not support directly from react native and also this is not supported in ios therefore only you could implement it with java native code in android. to do that you should write a service in android which handle this element life cycle.

Check this below by lord pooria

[RN-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542175/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-react-native)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Roy. I will have a look at this