# Any library in react native to display app over other app, just like swiggy does?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, window, overlay, floating

Swiggy floating app

[image]

How to implement display over other app in react native just like swiggy when the app minimizes a mini floating window of app appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw over other apps in React-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542175/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-react-native)

Comment: No it does not answer.

Comment: @MunishVira check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think I am late to get to this question.

This functionality is called as **Picture in Picture mode** for the app (in short PIP)

You can achieve this in android using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pip-android) package

install it and configure it as stated in the package info then use it like this:

```
import PipHandler, { usePipModeListener } from 'react-native-pip-android';

export default function App() {
  // Use this boolean to show / hide ui when pip mode changes
  const inPipMode = usePipModeListener();

  if (inPipMode) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>PIP Mode</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        These text components will be hidden in pip mode
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => PipHandler.enterPipMode(300, 214)}
        style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Click to Enter Pip Mode</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```